# How to satisfy dependencies for static compilation of 'dialog' tool for 32-bit

Tags: linux, gcc, undefined-reference

I want to compile the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/) program as 32-bit and statically linked executable in a 64-bit Ubuntu (16.04). This makes it easily distributable in a makeself archive without worrying about dependencies and such. I already built it 3 years ago that way and also took notes how to do it:

```
# get source and build-deps, then run:
./configure CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32 -static"
make
```

Now I modified the source (added additional option) but the rebuild fails with complaints about undefined reference to `Gpm_***` functions. This is unrelated to my modifications. Linking stage:

```
gcc -o dialog dialog.o -L. -ldialog -Wl,-rpath,/lib64   -L/lib64 -m32 -static -lncurses -ltermcap -lm 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `_nc_mouse_event':
(.text+0x632): undefined reference to `Gpm_GetEvent'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `enable_gpm_mouse':
(.text+0xcd2): undefined reference to `Gpm_Close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `enable_gpm_mouse':
(.text+0xd22): undefined reference to `Gpm_Open'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `enable_gpm_mouse':
(.text+0xd3a): undefined reference to `Gpm_Close'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `_nc_mouse_init':
(.text+0xe8c): undefined reference to `gpm_fd'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libncurses.a(lib_mouse.o): In function `mouse_activate':
(.text+0x1061): undefined reference to `gpm_fd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:211: recipe for target 'dialog' failed
make: *** [dialog] Error 1
```

The linker picks up the `libncurses.a` which seems to be ok to me as it is a static library archive. I don't understand why the Gpm_*** functions are not found. The `libgpm.a` provides these and is in the same directory. Even configuring with adding `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpm.a` to the LDFLAGS has no effect.

How can I make it link successfully?

**Update:**

See results with verbose linking (`-Wl,--verbose`) here: https://pastebin.com/AP48KMGt

Comment: Test compile "dialog", 32bits Ubuntu 14.04: `~/tmp/dialog-1.3-20160209$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-static" --enable-nls --with-ncursesw && make` → and got the exact same errors as your question is showing. ( I have all versions, all mainstream Linux OS installed, to test-build applications.)

Comment: You're compiling against 64-bit libraries; adding a 32-bit `libgpm.a` will not help with that.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Can you elaborate? I ran it with `-Wl,--verbose` and I can see no linking aginst 64-bit libraries. I also can confirm Knud Larsens test when I compile under 32-bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me after installing `gcc-multilib` (of course) and the i386 development packages for `libncurses5`, `libtinfo` and `libgpm`:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib libncurses5-dev:i386 libtinfo-dev:i386 libgpm-dev:i386
```

and linking explicitly with them:

```
gcc -o dialog dialog.o -L. -ldialog -g -O2 -m32 -static -lncurses -ltinfo -lgpm -lm
```

I got`./configure` to generate a working Makefile based on your example, with

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32 -static" LIBS="-lgpm"
$ make
...
gcc -o dialog dialog.o -L. -ldialog -m32 -Wl,-rpath,/lib64   -L/lib64 -m32 -static -lncurses -ltermcap -lm -lgpm
```

The result seems to be a valid i386 executable:

```
$ file dialog
dialog: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=4cbdb45a86cb5e6859db8c7cbeeaaa49baf45718, not stripped
```

Note: I tried passing `--host=i686-linux-gnu`, `--host=i686-pc-linux-gnu`, `--host=i386-linux-gnu` or `--host=i386-pc-linux-gnu` to `./configure`, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Wow. I don't think, setting the LIBS variable was necessary last year. Anyway, thanks very much. You made me happy and that bounty is well earned.